# How to Skip automatically entering into Assembly during debugging an Xcode Program?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, assembly, swift3

I am using Xcode 8.1 for building an IoS app using Swift V3. I created a break point in a line of my ViewController.swift file. However, when I am debugging my program its always entering into the assembly code section. I verified "debug->Always Show Disassembly", which is unchecked. I tried to debug my code by all the options, "Step out", "Step over", and "Step into" separately. But in each case its always entering into the Assembly portion. I do not have any other breakpoint except in once place in ViewController.swift. For example, I am always entering into the following sections regardless of I am following any of the debugging strategies.

```
    CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__:
    0x187012b44 <+0>:  mov    x8, x0
    0x187012b48 <+4>:  cbz    x8, 0x187012b60           ; <+28>
    0x187012b4c <+8>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
    0x187012b50 <+12>: mov    x29, sp
    0x187012b54 <+16>: mov    x0, x1
    0x187012b58 <+20>: blr    x8
->  0x187012b5c <+24>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #16
    0x187012b60 <+28>: ret
```

I just want to debug a single statement without entering into any functions or the assembly code. However, I can create a breakpoint in each line and press continue. I would be glad if someone has answer for any better solution than creating breakpoint in each line.

Comment: What is the "stop reason" shown in the PC ribbon in Xcode?  You can also see this in the command line if you run the "thread list" command.  From the description it sounds like you are crashing here.